# Divided differences at one point

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divided_differences) for different numbers $a_0, a_1, a_2,..., a_n$ we can write

$$f[a_0, a_1, a_2,...,a_n] = \sum_{j = 0}^n \frac{f(x_j)}{q'(x_j)}$$

where $q(x) = \prod_{i = 0}^n(x - x_i)$

Also, for the same numbers $(n + 1)$, we can write that:

$$f[a_0, a_0,...,a_0] = \frac{f^{(n)}(a_0)}{n!}$$

However, I'm wondering if we can write this expression in terms of polynomial $q$, as in the case of different nodes $a_0, a_1,...,a_n$. Could you please give a hand with justifying if its possible?

Comment: Your last formula is not correct. The nth derivative is not computed at $a_0$, but rather at an unknown point $\min a_i < \xi < \max a_i$.

Comment: Also, in the first formula, the $x_i$ should be $a_i$.